# Safari browser issue

Tags: wordpress, debugging, safari, bootstrap-4

So, my website looks good on chrome and most of the browser but on Safari some things dont t look as good as in Chrome for example.
My problem is that i don t know where to start 
- i tried on multiple devices with safari, the problem is the same on both of them (so i don`t think the browser, or clearing browser cookies will solve the problem as i already deleted the cache)
- maybe a problem with Bootstrap? ( i tought of this also but some things are working as bootstrap tells them to do, but some not, so if not all of them are disobeing Bootstrap rules this is not the problem)

here are some screenshots of the website on safari
[Etelle.ro/screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMxBN.png)

Any advice?

Many thanks

Comment: My site www.etelle.ro

Comment: You seem to be running Safari on Windows which means you must be using a truly ancient version. http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: i m not an apple user, but this browser issues appear also on apple devices with safari